# How to set selectbox options based on other selectbox value change in magento grid form

Tags: forms, magento, input, admin, magento-1.9

I have two select box field in my `grid form`. one is country and other one is states list.
I have two countries(`Us and Canada`). based on the country input selection i have to change the options value in state list input.

**How can i perform this task in magento adminhtml grid form side?. Please advice me on this.**

[image]

Comment: use Javascript, give the US related options a class and the Canada related options another. Add an onchange to the drop down which hides the non-selectable options. That'd be my approach.

Comment: If you end up with more than 2 countries the option list for all states can get really big though, you might end up wanting to use Ajax, but if I remember correctly Ajax was a bit of a hassle in Magento Admin.